# How to fix [WC] denying activation due to missing delegate Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, watchconnectivity, wcsession

Hi I have this function

```
extension UIViewController: WCSessionDelegate {
public func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {        
}
public func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {

}
public func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
}


//MARK: -SYNC DATA TO APPLE WATCH

func syncToAppleWatch(){
    var session: WCSession?
    if WCSession.isSupported() {//4.1
      session?.delegate = self
      session = WCSession.default//4.2
      session?.activate()//4.4
    }
```

}

I call "syncToAppleWatch" inside DidLoad. But I receive this error

```
 [WC] denying activation due to missing delegate
 [WC] WCSession has not been activated
```

How Can I fix it?

Comment: calling `session = ...` after `session?.delegate = ..` will remove the delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two lines make no sense

```
session?.delegate = self  // session is still nil here, delegate won't be set
session = WCSession.default
```

change the order to

```
session = WCSession.default
session?.delegate = self
```

Comment: I have changed the order but now I get only "[WC] WCSession has not been activated"

Comment: @TheCesco1988 So, one problem has been fixed.